# Spring AOP not working for Feign Client

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-cloud-feign

I having an aop-setup

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions { }

@Aspect
@Component
public class IgnoreHttpWebExceptionsAspect {

@Around(value = "@annotation(annotation)", argNames = "joinPoint, annotation")
public Object ignoreHttpClientErrorExceptions(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions annotation)
  throws Throwable {
try {
  //do something
 } catch (HttpClientErrorException ex) {
  //do something
 }
}
```

If I add this annotation(`@IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions`) in service layer,

```
@Service
public class SentenceServiceImpl implements SentenceService {

 @Autowired
 VerbClient verbClient;

 @HystrixCommand(ignoreExceptions = {HttpClientErrorException.class})
 @IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions
 public ResponseEntity<String> patch(String accountId, String patch) {
    return verbClient.patchPreferences(accountId, patch);
 }
}
```

My AOP is invoked.

But when I add this annotation(`@IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions`) in my feign layer.

```
@FeignClient(value = "account")
@RequestMapping(value = "/url")
public interface VerbClient {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/preferences", method = RequestMethod.PATCH, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  @IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions
  ResponseEntity<String> patchPreferences(@PathVariable("id") String accountId, String patchJson);
}
```

AOP is not invoked.

Any idea why aop is not get invoked, when I add the annotation in feign-layer?

Dependency added:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: can you try adding @EnableAspectJAutoProxy on your @ Configuration class ?

Answer (score 1):

Annotation on method is not supposed to inherited.

Hence spring AOP cannot intercept your methods.

Event `@Inherited` only support inheritance from [superclass to subclasses.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html)

So in this case, you should try another pointcut, depend on your need:

```
// Match all method in interface VerbClient and subclasses implementation
@Around(value = "execution(* com.xxx.VerbClient+.*(..))")

// Match all method in interface VerbClient and subclasses implementation
@Around(value = "execution(* com.xxx.VerbClient+.*(..))")

// Match all method `patchPreferences` in interface VerbClient and subclasses implementation
@Around(value = "execution(* com.xxx.VerbClient+.patchPreferences(..))")

// Or make IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions work for Type, 
// and match all method with in annotated interface and subclass implementation
// (@Inherited must be used)
// By this way, you can mark your VerbClient feign interface with this annotation
@Around(value = "execution(* (com.yyy.IgnoreHttpClientErrorExceptions *+).*(..))")
```