# Is there a way to record response times of feign client

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-feign, openfeign

```
@FeignClient(...)
public interface SomeClient {
@RequestMapping(value = "/someUrl", method = POST, consumes = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<String> createItem(...);

}
```

Is there a way to find the response times for createItem api call? 
We are using spring boot, actuator, prometheus.

Comment: There are numerous way, I would think you want a request interceptor. There are many tutorials, such as https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-handlerinterceptor. Or you could use a pointcut for any methods that meet a pattern, this might be more difficult to get working when you only define the interface with Feign https://www.baeldung.com/spring-performance-logging. Also, you can connect with JMX to monitor, https://github.com/iyzico/boot-mon is one tool but there are more.

Comment: @Lavy, since the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56140774/is-there-a-way-to-record-response-times-of-feign-client/58158218#58158218 has been accepted by many, could you please try by your side, then accept my answer

Answer (score 8):

We have straight forward as well as a customized way for logging the feign clients request and response (including the response time). We have to inject the feign.Logger.Level bean, that's it.

1. **THE DEFAULT/ STRAIGHT FORWARD WAY**

```
@Bean
Logger.Level feignLoggerLevel() {
  return Logger.Level.BASIC;
}
```

there are BASIC,FULL,HEADERS,NONE(default) logging levels are available  [for more details](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_logging)

The above bean injection will give you the logging of feign request and response in the below format:

**REQUEST**:

[refer](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/335835022b6d94b47200a0067766c8ef66fb8c95/core/src/main/java/feign/Logger.java#L48)

```
log(configKey, "---> %s %s HTTP/1.1", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url());

ex:2019-09-26 12:50:12.163 [DEBUG] [http-nio-4200-exec-5] [com.sample.FeignClient:72] [FeignClient#getUser] ---> END HTTP (0-byte body)
```

where the `configkey` means `FeignClientClassName#FeignClientCallingMethodName` ex: `ApiClient#apiMethod`.

**RESPONSE**

[refer](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/335835022b6d94b47200a0067766c8ef66fb8c95/core/src/main/java/feign/Logger.java#L86)

```
log(configKey, "<--- HTTP/1.1 %s%s (%sms)", status, reason, elapsedTime);

ex:2019-09-26 12:50:12.163 [DEBUG] [http-nio-4200-exec-5] [com.sample.FeignClient:72] [FeignClient#getUser] <--- HTTP/1.1 200 OK (341ms)
```

the `elapsedTime` is what the response time taken for the API call.

**NOTE**: If you prefer the default way of the feign client logging then we have to consider the underlying application logging level as well because the `feign.Slf4jLogger` class logging with the feign request and response details with the `DEBUG` level ([refer](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/335835022b6d94b47200a0067766c8ef66fb8c95/slf4j/src/main/java/feign/slf4j/Slf4jLogger.java#L71)). If the underlying logging level above DEBUG then you may need to specify the explicit logger for the `feign` logging package/class otherwise it will not work.

2. **THE CUSTOMIZED WAY**
     If you prefer logging with your customized format then you can extend the `feign.Logger` class and customize your logging. For a typical example if I want to log the header details of request and response in a single line as a list(by default Logger.Level.HEADERS prints the header in multiple lines):

```
package com.test.logging.feign;

import feign.Logger;
import feign.Request;
import feign.Response;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.io.IOException;

import static feign.Logger.Level.HEADERS;

@Slf4j
public class customFeignLogger extends Logger {

    @Override
    protected void logRequest(String configKey, Level logLevel, Request request) {

        if (logLevel.ordinal() >= HEADERS.ordinal()) {
            super.logRequest(configKey, logLevel, request);
        } else {
            int bodyLength = 0;
            if (request.requestBody().asBytes() != null) {
                bodyLength = request.requestBody().asBytes().length;
            }
            log(configKey, "---> %s %s HTTP/1.1 (%s-byte body) %s", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url(), bodyLength, request.headers());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Response logAndRebufferResponse(String configKey, Level logLevel, Response response, long elapsedTime)
            throws IOException {
        if (logLevel.ordinal() >= HEADERS.ordinal()) {
            super.logAndRebufferResponse(configKey, logLevel, response, elapsedTime);
        } else {
            int status = response.status();
            Request request = response.request();
            log(configKey, "<--- %s %s HTTP/1.1 %s (%sms) %s", request.httpMethod().name(), request.url(), status, elapsedTime, response.headers());
        }
        return response;
    }


    @Override
    protected void log(String configKey, String format, Object... args) {
        log.debug(format(configKey, format, args));
    }

    protected String format(String configKey, String format, Object... args) {
        return String.format(methodTag(configKey) + format, args);
    }
}
```

also we have to inject the customFeignLogger class bean

```
  @Bean
    public customFeignLogger customFeignLogging() {
        return new customFeignLogger();
    }
```

If you are building FeignClient by yourself then you can build it with the customized logger:

```
 Feign.builder().logger(new customFeignLogger()).logLevel(Level.BASIC).target(SomeFeignClient.class,"http://localhost:8080");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following annotation to your project.

```
package com.example.annotation

@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DebugTracking {
    @Aspect
    @Component
    public static class DebugTrackingAspect {
        @Around("@annotation(com.example.annotation.DebugTracking)")
        public Object trackExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start(joinPoint.toShortString());

            Exception exceptionThrown = null;

            try {
                // Execute the joint point as usual
                return joinPoint.proceed();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                exceptionThrown = ex;
                throw ex;

            } finally {
                stopWatch.stop();

                System.out.println(String.format("%s took %dms.", stopWatch.getLastTaskName(), stopWatch.getLastTaskTimeMillis()));

                if (exceptionThrown != null) {
                    System.out.println(String.format("Exception thrown: %s", exceptionThrown.getMessage()));
                    exceptionThrown.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then annotate the methods you want to track in your `@FeignClient` with `@DebugTracking`.

Comment: annotation on feignclient method is not getting invoked. I tried using @Around(value = "execution(* com.xxx.VerbClient+.*(..))") without annotation and is working now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51914315/spring-aop-not-working-for-feign-client

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following (with Spring and Lombok) :

```
@Configuration // from Spring
@Slf4j // from Lombok
public class MyFeignConfiguration {
    @Bean // from Spring
    public MyFeignClient myFeignClient() {
        return Feign.builder()
            .logger(new Logger() {
                @Override
                protected void log(String configKey, String format, Object... args) {
                    LOG.info( String.format(methodTag(configKey) + format, args)); // LOG is the Lombok Slf4j object
                }
            })
            .logLevel(Logger.Level.BASIC) // see https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html#_feign_logging
            .target(MyFeignClient.class,"http://localhost:8080");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct way doing this is using custom logger as pointed above. Using @Aspect is wrong. With that you create additional wrapper around the service. Feign already records this metric. Get that metric from feign.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).